Next.js Project: Unable to Resolve @solana/web3.js Module
Problem Description
We are encountering a recurring error when attempting to run a Next.js project that integrates the Solana and TipLink wallet adapters. The error message indicates that the module @solana/web3.js cannot be found:
sql

Module not found: Can't resolve '@solana/web3.js'
Import trace for the requested module:
../node_modules/@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile/lib/esm/index.js
../node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/WalletProvider.js
../node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/index.js
../node_modules/@tiplink/wallet-adapter-react-ui/lib/esm/TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2.js
../node_modules/@tiplink/wallet-adapter-react-ui/lib/esm/index.js
./src/Components/WalletProvider.tsx
./src/pages/_app.tsx

Steps Taken

Cleaned and Reinstalled Node Modules: Deleted the node_modules
directory and package-lock.json file. Cleared the npm cache.
Reinstalled dependencies
Verified Installation of @solana/web3.js:The package @solana/web3.js is installed and listed in the npm ls output.

Project Configuration:
Next.js version: 14.2.5
Package versions for wallet adapters:
@solana/wallet-adapter-react@0.15.35
@solana/wallet-adapter-base@0.9.23
@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui@0.8.0
@tiplink/wallet-adapter@2.1.20
@solana/web3.js@1.95.1
Current Configuration Files
WalletProvider.tsx:

    ```Import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react';
import { WalletProvider as SolanaWalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { TipLinkWalletAdapter } from '@tiplink/wallet-adapter';
import {
    WalletModalProvider,
    TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2
} from '@tiplink/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const MyWalletProvider: FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {    
    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new TipLinkWalletAdapter({ 
                title: "Your dApp Name", 
                clientId: "",
                theme: "dark"  // or "light" or "system"
            }),
        ],
        []
    );

    const { query, isReady } = useRouter();

    return (
        <SolanaWalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
            <WalletModalProvider>
                <TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2
                    isReady={isReady}
                    query={query}
                >
                    {children}
                </TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2>
            </WalletModalProvider>
        </SolanaWalletProvider>
    );
}; 

_app.tsx:
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { MyWalletProvider } from '../Components/WalletProvider'; // Correct import path

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <MyWalletProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MyWalletProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp; 

Issue:
Despite the module @solana/web3.js being installed and listed in the npm ls output, Next.js fails to resolve it during runtime.
Request for Assistance
I am seeking assistance in resolving this module resolution issue. Any insights or recommendations on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
